Using the escape function to concatenate the title with the colors together to show on my store
I am having issue to concatenate the title with the colors in this form ( " Title (color, color, color)" ).
Script works great with "Title": escape ((title)) but now when adding (coloror)) I get this error
"Title": escape ((title) (coloror)) ,  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable "
Script is long, Snippet of script:
print('Title: ',title)
# Print the extracted data
for data in product_data:
    print(f"Color: {data['color']}")
    print(f"Price: {data['price']}")
    print(f"Width: {data['width']}")
    print(f"Image URL: {data['image_url']}")
    print(f"Available Sizes: {', '.join(data['sizes'])}")
    print(f"ror: {data}")
    print("-" * 50)

coloror = ', '.join(data['color'] for data in product_data)
    

item = {
    "Item": {
        "Title": escape ((title) (coloror)) 

I don't have much experience with Python.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

The issue is with how you’re concatenating the title and coloror variables inside escape().
The error occurs because Python interprets (title) as a function call, but title is a string, not a callable object. Instead, you should properly concatenate the strings before passing them to escape(). You could have something like
    item = {
    "Item": {
        "Title": escape(title + " (" + coloror + ")") 
    }
}

There’s more information on string operations here https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

How can yyou suggest this as an answer? True, there is an obvious syntax error in the OP but you have no idea what escape() is and what it expects as its arguments

You are right, but what I did was to concatenate title and coloror into a single string with the " (" and ")" around coloror, and then passing the result to escape(). Notice that the core issue in the original code was the incorrect syntax for concatenating title and coloror, and once the concatenation is done properly, passing the result to escape() (assuming it's a function that handles strings) should work.

Thank you Ufia, This all I needed. It works. .. Your answer is very USEFUL

need to import html,escape() frist

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
